# Bash - Extracting URL from HTML by pattern

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I have a Bash script that fetches a huge HTML, using cURL, that contains URLs that follow a certain pattern.

Pattern:

```
https://mycoolsite.com/deliveries/{UUID}.bin
```

Example:

```
https://mycoolsite.com/deliveries/e4e8c143b2c59f58eb52a03f2cc2d36c4a9fee3b.bin
```

The HTML has one single line with a list of JSON objects like this:

```
{"type":"hd_mp4_video",...,"container":"mp4"...,{"max_bitrate":290836,...},"url":"https://mycoolsite.com/deliveries/e4e8c143b2c59f58eb52a03f2cc2d36c4a9fee3b.bin","created_at":1556973749,"segment_duration":3,"opt_vbitrate":5625}
```

Other JSON objects with different *"type"* exist, but my complete use case is to look for the *hd_mp4_video*.

However, I can work my way out if I can find all URLs that match the pattern or if I can pick the n-th match exactly.

I would like to do something like

```
origin_url="https://mycoolsite.com/embed/iframe/2dkmdf59gy"
html=$(curl GET $origin_url)
bin_url=$(#Extract the URL(s))
echo bin_url
```

Comment: Can you show use an extract of the html that is fetched?

Comment: I've added more details of the HTML itself.

Comment: If this is json then use a proper json parser such as jq.

Comment: The JSON itself is embedded inside the HTML text. Probably treating everything as plain text through sed is the easiest way, rather than parsing properly. The JSON part could be nice to use to fetch the exact URL to the mp4, but, in my case, if I find all URLs I can work around.

Comment: Is that extract on one line?

Comment: Yes, the HTML has one line with the list of objects like the one shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example "UUID" value you've given seems to consist only of digits and lowercase characters, no minus signs as separators, and 40 characters exactly, so the appropriate POSIX extended regular expression to match these URLs would be:

```
https://mycoolsite.com/[0-9a-f]{40}.bin
```

(If there can be differences, look into POSIX **extended** regex syntax and tweak the regex accordingly.)

Given that, you could extract them with the `sed` utility:

```
curl "$url" | sed -rn 's_.*(https://mycoolsite.com/[0-9a-f]{40}.bin).*_\1_p'
```

Note that I'm using `_` instead of `/` as the separator for sed's `s` command, because the regex contains `/` characters.

The `r` switch to sed enables extended regex syntax, and the `n` switch tells sed not to print anything automatically.

The `p` option at the end of the `s` command then explicitly prints any lines in which a successful regex substitution was made. In this case, that substitution removes anything before and after the matched regex.

Note that while this will print multiple URLs in the input, it will **not** print two URLs appearing **within the same line** because the regex we've used will ditch anything after the first match in a line.

Comment: Thanks Taylan, very good explanation. I realized the first match is not exactly my use case. I have updated the question asking for the n-th match or the list with all the strings. Is it possible to tweak the sed command to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl .... | sed -rn '/type:hd_mp4_video/s@(^.*url:)(.*)(,created.*$)@\2@p'
```

Search for lines with type and hd_mp4_video. Split the line into three sections based on regular expressions and substitute the line for only the second section (the actual URL), printing the result.

Comment: I'm getting no output from it. Should I replace this _url_ with something or should I use it as a variable later on in the script?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any need to amend anything but the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Perl version to print the whole list :

```
curl ... | perl -ne 'map { print("$_\n") } /"url":"([^"]+)/g'
```